# Time Zone information for Google Calendar Event Query

Tags: timezone, google-calendar-api, country-codes

I would like to use following url to retrive the hoildays for each country

```
http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/tr.turkish%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/full
```

As i am developing application for **windows phone**, i don't know in which country it will be used.
So i am trying to find the language.timezone combination which i can formulate to use.

I check the following link for timezone names, http://www.timezoneconverter.com/cgi-bin/zonehelp.tzc
but its different than what google accepts.

like, Turkey listed as **Europe/Istanbul**, but google acceptes as **tr.turkish**. if I try **tr.Europe/Istanbul**, i get error.

Another example South Africa is accepted as **en.sa**. I can't find the corelation between country codes and timezone codes.

is there any way to find the list for all countries to code in program that google accepts?

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: There is also option like: http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/[CALENDAR_ID]/public/full where CALENDAR_ID is turkish__tr@holiday.calendar.google.com, but still don't get where i can find the list for turkish__tr part

Comment: You do realize this API is scheduled for deprecation later this year, right?  [See the big red bar at the top of the docs](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v2/reference).

Comment: Also, what does this have to do with time zones?  You haven't made that clear at all.  If you're just looking for the list of available calendars, [here's a guide](http://www.guidingtech.com/2329/add-public-holidays-google-calendar/).  Since ulitimately these are just predefined calendars with a given name, you'll have to check the names of the ones you are interested in.  It doesn't make sense to assume that there is any uniformity without checking.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for information, my intention was to add Holidays to my WP8 program for every country, hoping that i can acceess google calender for that with timezone/country info. but seems not that easy.